# Change UserName for a TFS Workspace

Tags: tfs, workspace

We recently changed domains for our entire network, and I am trying to find a way to migrate my TFS workspace from my old Domain\Username to the new Domain\Username without losing any pending changes.

Note also that I need a solution to accomplish this via the command line, as Visual Studio won't let me access the old workspace from the old domain.

Answer (score 3):

See the MSDN article about the [Workspaces Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/54dkh0y3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). You can invoke tf workspace with an argument /updateUserName. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I just migrated my TFS server from my old domain to a new domain because my organization had a company name change. After the migration, I had to overcome several issues and eventually I was left with the development team getting TFS14045 error messages. The fix to this problem was simply having the developers issue the following command from their Visual Studio command prompt.

tf workspaces /updateUserName:OLDDOMAIN\olddomainusername /s:http://[tfsserver]:8080/tfs

I found that if multiple developers had logged into that workstation and created workspaces with visual studio that I had to issue this command for each domain account until I get them all. After I did this procedure I was then able to remove their corresponding records form the tbl_identity table of the TFS_Configuration database on my TFS server so that I wouldn't then also have to look at duplicate accounts for the same person (one for their old domain account and one for their new domain account) inside my TFS collection. Leaving this record in place also created another error that you will get if a developer breaks the build and TFS tries to create a auto generated work item for that developer to fix the build. If both the old domain account and the new domain account is present in the TFS collection (recorded in the tbl_identity table...) then TFS will not know which user account to use when making the work item for the broken build.

Good luck and I apologize if this is too rambling to read but I am in a hurry and I hate reading posts that leave out detail ;-)